# Age in Years and Days

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to display the ages of a person in Years and Days.

EX: someone born January 26, 1934 is 89 years and 149 days.

How would this be calculated in Javascript?

Thanks, John

I can calculate it in years, months and days. just don't know how for it to be just years and days.

```js
function getAge(date_1, date_2)
{
    //convert to UTC
    var date2_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(date_2.getUTCFullYear(), date_2.getUTCMonth(), date_2.getUTCDate()));
    var date1_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(date_1.getUTCFullYear(), date_1.getUTCMonth(), date_1.getUTCDate()));

    var yAppendix, mAppendix, dAppendix;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    var days = date2_UTC.getDate() - date1_UTC.getDate();
    if (days < 0) { date2_UTC.setMonth(date2_UTC.getMonth() - 1); days += Math.round(DaysInMonth(date2_UTC)); }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    var Tmonths = date2_UTC.getMonth() - date1_UTC.getMonth();
    if (Tmonths < 0) { date2_UTC.setFullYear(date2_UTC.getFullYear() - 1); Tmonths += 12; }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    var years = date2_UTC.getFullYear() - date1_UTC.getFullYear();

    /* Default */  yAppendix = " year";                   mAppendix = " month";                dAppendix = " day";
    if (years > 1) yAppendix = " years"; if (Tmonths > 1) mAppendix = " months"; if (days > 1) dAppendix = " days";

    return padout(years) + yAppendix + ", " + padout(Tmonths) + mAppendix + ", and " + padout(days) + dAppendix;
}
```

Comment: `floor(days/365)` years, `days % 365` days

Comment: "I can calculate it in years, months and days. just don't know how for it to be just years and days." Please post your code, show what you have tried, then state where you get stuck or don't understand. Otherwise this is just a math question instead of a programming question. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Bijan wrong. Date arithmetic is never that simple. For examples, your snippet does not take leap years into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateAge(birthDate) {
  var today = new Date();
  var birthDateObj = new Date(birthDate);

  // Calculate the number of full years
  var years = today.getFullYear() - birthDateObj.getFullYear();

  // Check if the current date has passed the birth date in this year
  if (
    today.getMonth() < birthDateObj.getMonth() ||
    (today.getMonth() === birthDateObj.getMonth() &&
      today.getDate() < birthDateObj.getDate())
  ) {
    years--;
  }

  // Calculate the number of days
  var birthDateThisYear = new Date(today.getFullYear(), birthDateObj.getMonth(), birthDateObj.getDate());
  var days = Math.floor((today - birthDateThisYear) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  // Account for leap years
  var leapYears = countLeapYears(birthDateObj.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear());
  days -= leapYears;

  return { years: years, days: days };
}

function countLeapYears(startYear, endYear) {
  // Count the number of leap years between startYear and endYear (both inclusive)
  var count = 0;
  for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
    if ((year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || year % 400 === 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

// Example usage
var birthDate = '1990-06-01';
var age = calculateAge(birthDate);
console.log('Total years:', age.years);
console.log('Total days:', age.days);
```

Comment: Anwar Ali, thank you

Comment: The above code works fine if the birthdate has already passed (ie: January 1), but if the birthdate has not happened yet (ie: July 1) it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).